# Can I write a matlab patch straight to file

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure

I am trying to render video from patches. The video is at 25fps and my code is rendering each patch to the screen before writing it to an image. I have tried the 'visible', 'off' option in patch but this just results in blank frames in my movie. Can I use the patch function so that it writes to a file, but doesn't render to screen?

```
for k = 1:length(obj.shape)
    fig = patch('Vertices', obj.shape(k).vertices',...
    'Faces', obj.shape(k).faces', 'FaceColor', [0.8 0.5 0.2],...
    'LineStyle', 'none', 'FaceLighting', 'phong', 'Visible', 'on');
    light('Position', [1 0 0], 'Style', 'infinite');
    View(180, 90);
    f = getframe(gcf);
    close(gcf);
    imwrite(f.cdata, [directory '/frame_' int2str(k) '.jpg'], 'jpg');
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `getframe` doesn't work with invisibility is that it captures the actual screen content. You can achieve what you want if you are willing to use `print` instead:

```
figure
set(gcf, 'Visible', 'off')
for ...
    < draw your animation frame >
    print('-r300', '-djpeg', '[directory '/frame_' int2str(k) '.jpg'])
end
```

The drawback is that your saved image won't look exactly like on screen, because it has been generated by Matlab's printing mechanism. You can tweak its appearance though by specifying the resolution, setting the figure location and size on the "page" etc. etc.

Btw., it is probably not a good idea to make a new figure for each frame, just reuse one and overwrite its contents. Also, for postprocessing into a video, animated gif, etc. it would be better to use a lossless file format like PNG.

Comment: Yes this is the solution having the added advantage of not displaying the plot axis by default.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that [getframe() sets the figure to visible](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/236176) (you can see that by typing "*edit getframe*", lines 100-125). I'm not sure whether there exists any straightforward way to do what you are asking, though I entirely understand your need.